# Xamarin iOS - fit label in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xamarin, uilabel

I'm having a problem with my label expanding beyond the cell itself. the label is created programatically, therefore there is no Nib out there.
I think the way to do it right is to put constraints between the cell and the label, but I don't know how.
Here's a snippet code

```
 UITableViewCell CreateMessageCell()
    {
        var cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, null);
        cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        cell.TextLabel.Font = detailFont;
        cell.TextLabel.Lines = 0;
        cell.TextLabel.TextColor = contentColor;
        cell.TextLabel.Text = viewModel.Body;
        return cell;
    }
```

And this is an image to demonstrate the problem
[Label Extending Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7fOc.png)

Comment: Are you using `UITableView.AutomaticDimension` for the `RowHeight`?

Comment: Indeed, eventually I managed to do a trick there

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: Click on the image and you'll see

Comment: Sorry. I mean, how did you resolve the issue? What was the fix?

Comment: I've managed to check if it's an iPhone or an iPad, and for iPhone it worked fine, but for iPad I gave it the cell.TextLabel.AlignmentHeight.Height * 2 in GetHeightForRow

Comment: If you use `AutomaticDimension`, then you shouldn't be returning a height in `GetHeightForRow` - that's a conflicting configuration. If you use automatic heights,  you can't then give it a concrete height. There is a way to return an estimated height, but it isn't always necessary.